# Taxonomy - Exclude post format from showing on page

Tags: taxonomy, post-formats

Im trying to set up a taxonomy to hide a post_format on a particular page.

I have created the below which stops that post_format from displaying on the page but it also hides it in the 'Posts' page on the CMS. Is there a way to get around this?

```
    function exclude_campaigns( $query ) {
        if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
            $tax_query = array( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'post-format-link' ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            ) );
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_campaigns' );
```

Updated function:

```
// Exclude post-format from one particular page
function exclude_campaigns( $query ) {
    // is_page() allows for page ID, page title or page slug
    if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_page(239) ) {
        $tax_query = array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-link' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ) );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_campaigns' );
```

Comment: You're applying this action on the main WP query and on the home page. The home page would includes posts if you've set your latest posts to be displayed on the front page via your "Settings > Reading" options. Are you wanting the post-format to not appear on ANY pages, or just one particular page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah Im trying to hide this post-format on just one particular page.

Comment: "hides it in the 'Posts' page on the CMS" What do you mean by this.

Comment: In the posts page it doesnt display any post with this post-format

Comment: Backend or front end

Comment: That query hides it in the backend and frontend

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to hide a post-format on one particular page, then the function below should work.

```
<?php
// Exclude post-format from one particular page
function exclude_campaigns( $query ) {
    // is_page() allows for page ID, page title or page slug
    if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_page( INSERT_PAGE_ID_HERE ) ) {
        $tax_query = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-link' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_campaigns' );
```

Comment: When I put the page id in Im getting this error:

Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\wordpress-btb\wp-includes\query.php on line 4337 Call Stack

Comment: @adam The you are accessing it wrong. Update your question with your new code - keep in mind that you have a PHP syntax error and that you might want to read about objects in PHP in general.

Comment: Oh right ok thanks for the reply but how I am accessing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) alters all queries, back-end and front-end, new instances of `WP_Query` and the default main query. You should use `pre_get_posts` in conjunction with the [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

The most important conditional tags here are:

- [`is_main_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) -> This is used to target the main query only, excludes all custom instances of `WP_Query`
- [`is_admin()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) -> Very important, with this conditional you can target only back-end queries. For this purpose, you are going to need the negative `!is_admin()` as you need to target the frond-end, not the back-end (admin side)

The rest of the conditionals can be used to target specific pages. You need to check what you need and apply it as needed.

```
if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
```

should become

```
if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
```

which will only apply your changes to the front-end main query on the home page

I do believe that `is_page()` is inappropriate here. You will need to check what kind of page this is and then use the correct conditional tag accordingly. For instance, if this is the home page, use `is_home()`, or if it is a category page, use `is_category()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pieter for the detailed reply, but using "if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ){" does not hide the post-format on the page. I even tried removing " && $query->is_home()" and that doesnt work either! I'm completely stumped

Comment: On which page is this exactly. Is this an archive type page like a taxonomy or category page or maybe a home page or static front page. Are you sure that the query you are targeting is actually the main query